# Auto Clear Range on Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am a teacher trying to make my life easier. 
I need a script to auto clear data from my google sheet on Fridays at 11 PM.

My sheet is called 'COrder1' and the range I want to clear is A5:J56

I have been playing with it but can't get it figured out. Can anyone help with a script to do this? I am new to this.

Comment: Post your code first

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
function clearMyJunk() 
{
  var dt=new Date();
  if(dt.getDay()==5)//If its friday
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('COrder1').getRange('A5:J56').clearContent();
  }
}

//put this function in your onOpen() function
//The created trigger will run sometime between 23:00 to 24:00
function clearMyJunkTrigger()
{
  if(!isMyTrigger)//This keeps it from creating more than one trigger
  {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('clearMyJunk').timeBased().atHour(23).everyDays(1).create();
  }
}

function isMyTrigger(funcName)
{
  var r=false;
  if(funcName)
  {
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    var allHandlers=[];
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++)
    {
      allHandlers.push(allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction());
    }
    if(allHandlers.indexOf(funcName)>-1)
    {
      r=true;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```